# Sending general signal to child process of supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I am using supervisord to manage a bunch of processes.  Is it possible to use supervisorctl to send arbitrary signals to these processes without actually stopping them and setting stopsignal?

Answer (score 17):

Until 3.2.0 (released November 2015), `supervisorctl` had no support for sending arbitrary signals to the processes it manages.

From 3.2.0 onwards, use `supervisorctl signal`:

```
signal <signal name> <name>     Signal a process
signal <signal name> <gname>:*      Signal all processes in a group
signal <signal name> <name> <name>  Signal multiple processes or groups
signal <signal name> all        Signal all processes
```

so

```
supervisorctl signal HUP all
```

would send `SIGHUP` to all processes managed by supervisor.

Until 3.2.0, you instead could use `supervisorctl status` to list the `pid`s of the managed processes. Then use `kill` to send signals to those `pid`s. With a little `sed` magic, you can even extract those `pid`s to be acceptable as input to the `kill` command:

```
kill -HUP `bin/supervisorctl status | sed -n '/RUNNING/s/.*pid \([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p'`
```

would also send `SIGHUP` to all active processes under `supervisord` control.

Comment: My preference has been to do that sort of thing as one big `sed` command like: `sed -n '/RUNNING/s/.*pid \([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p'` instead of `grep | awk | sed | paste` etc.

Comment: @MarkHarviston: My UNIX command-line fu is lacking somewhat, your approach may very well be better than mine.

Comment: what a pity I want to send hup from supervisorctl :((((

Answer (score 7):

[As of 3.2.0](http://supervisord.org/changes.html), you CAN now send arbitrary signals to processes!

```
$ supervisord --version
3.2.0


$ supervisorctl signal help
Error: signal requires a signal name and a process name
signal <signal name> <name>     Signal a process
signal <signal name> <gname>:*      Signal all processes in a group
signal <signal name> <name> <name>  Signal multiple processes or groups
signal <signal name> all        Signal all processes


$ supervisorctl signal HUP gateway
gateway: signalled
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a [third-party plugin for supervisor](http://supervisord.org/plugins.html#third-party-plugins-and-libraries-for-supervisor) called [mr.laforge](https://github.com/fschulze/mr.laforge) which

> Lets you easily make sure that supervisord and specific processes controlled by it are running from within shell and Python scripts. **Also adds a kill command to supervisor that makes it possible to send arbitrary signals to child processes.**